# I want to know why the results are different in these two ways

Tags: go, swap

```
func main() {
    var a int = 10
    var b int = 20
    swap(&a,&b)
    fmt.Println(a,b)

    var c int = 10
    var d int = 20
    swap2(&c,&d)
    fmt.Println(c,d)
}
func swap(x, y *int) {
    *x = *y
    *y = *x
}
func swap2(x, y *int) {
    *x,*y= *y,*x
}
```

//I want to know why the results are different in these two ways

//20 20

//20 10

Comment: Please fix the title, and specify what language you are using, preferably by tagging.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `swap2(&c,&d)` results in different values being set to `c` and `d` is because this function consists of a single assignment statement while `swap(&a,&b)` consists of two assignment statements.  Assignment statements have a particular evaluation order in go. From the [language specifications](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments):

> The assignment proceeds in two phases. First, the operands of index expressions and pointer indirections (including implicit pointer indirections in selectors) on the left and the expressions on the right are all evaluated in the usual order. Second, the assignments are carried out in left-to-right order.

With this in mind, let's annotate `swap(x, y *int)`:

```
// x points to an int with value 10,
// y points to an int with value 20.
*x = *y  // 1.
*y = *x  // 2.
```

The first assignment statement occurs first, so do that:

```
// x points to an int with value 10,
// y points to an int with value 20.
*x = *y  // 1. (value of int pointed to by x) = (value of int pointed to by y)
// Now x points to an int with value 20.
*y = *x  // 2.
```

After the first assignment statement finishes, the second assignment statement is run:

```
// x points to an int with value 10,
// y points to an int with value 20.
*x = *y  // 1. (value of int pointed to by x) = (value of int pointed to by y)
// Now x points to an int with value 20.
*y = *x  // 2. (value of int pointed to by y) = (value of int pointed to by x)
// Now y points to an int with value 20.
```

However, because `swap2` uses only a single assignment statement, we have to be careful about what happens in what order. The specifications say that the pointer indirections on the left *and* the expressions on the right are evaluated at the same time:

```
// x points to an int with value 10
// y points to an int with value 20
*x,*y = *y,*x
// 1. (value of int pointed to by x), (value of int pointed to by y) = 20, 10
```

Second, the assignments are carried out in left-to-right order. But because we have already evaluated the right-hand side of the statement, those are just values.

```
// x points to an int with value 10
// y points to an int with value 20
*x,*y = *y,*x
// 1. (value of int pointed to by x), (value of int pointed to by y) = 20, 10
// 2. Now x points to an int with value 20, y points to an int with value 10
```

Put another way, `swap2` does the same thing as this function:

```
swap3(x, y *int) {
    valueX := *x
    valueY := *y
    *x = valueY
    *y = valueX
}
```

The advantage of the form of `swap2` is that the function does not explicitly allocate unnecessary temporary variables.